# Golang - Set custom TraceID and SpanID in OpenTelemetry

Tags: go, trace, open-telemetry, otel

I have 2 Async  (non-HTTP) jobs running in different processes. I want to use my own generated TraceIDs and SpanIDs for all Traces and Spans using OpenTelemetry library for GO. (I am using Signoz for visualization but it shouldn't matter).

1.) How do I set a TraceID and SpanID for the root span
2.) How do I set a spanID and point it to the custom root span with TraceId I created in (1)

Below is for (2) but I see missing traces.
`

```
b3 := []byte("9cec1f9bb461a96e023efebc879da11c")
copy(ptid[:], b3)

b4 := []byte("3fc56ecf2453bda8")
var parentSpanCtx = trace.NewSpanContext(trace.SpanContextConfig{
    TraceID:    ptid,
    SpanID:     trace.SpanID(b4),
    TraceFlags: trace.FlagsSampled,
    Remote:     true,
})`
    var parentCtx = trace.ContextWithSpanContext(context.Background(), parentsc)
ctx, span := tracer.Start(parentCtx, stage.Name)
```

I tried setting SpanContext for childSpans with the correct Parent TraceID and SpanId but it does not work. It shows as missing spans for root.

Answer (score 1):

1. How do I set a TraceID and SpanID for the root span?

Open telemetry support Custom IDGenerator for generating TraceId and SpanID as per your logic. You can use it while creating trace provider (sample of aws xray)

```golang
NewIDs(ctx context.Context) (trace.TraceID, trace.SpanID)
```

```golang
sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
    sdktrace.WithIDGenerator(xray.NewIDGenerator()),
)
```

2. How do I set a spanID and point it to the custom root span with TraceId I created in (1)

a. Not a remote trace (ctx is accessible while trying to create new Span)
IDGenerator has method to get new spanId based on root span (trace)

```golang
NewSpanID(ctx context.Context, traceID trace.TraceID) trace.SpanID
```

b. In remote trace (server to server calls)
You can use `TextMapPropagator`. This can help in customizing trace id and span id sharing and retrieving between servers for context propogation

```golang
otel.SetTextMapPropagator(xray.Propagator{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which answers both (1) and (2)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/attribute"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/stdout/stdouttrace"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/resource"
    sdktrace "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk/trace"
    "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
)

func main() {
    // Create a trace provider with a custom exporter (e.g., stdout exporter for testing)
    exporter, err := stdouttrace.New(stdouttrace.WithPrettyPrint())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error creating exporter: %v", err)
    }
    resources, err := resource.New(
        context.Background(),
        resource.WithAttributes(
            attribute.String("service.name", "serviceName"),
            attribute.String("library.language", "go"),
        ),
    )
    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithBatcher(exporter),
        sdktrace.WithResource(resources),
    )
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)

    // Manually create a custom TraceID and SpanID for the root span
    traceID := trace.TraceID([16]byte{0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0xfe, 0xdc, 0xba, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10})
    spanID := trace.SpanID([8]byte{0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77})

    ctx := trace.ContextWithRemoteSpanContext(
        context.Background(),
        trace.NewSpanContext(trace.SpanContextConfig{
            TraceID:    traceID,
            SpanID:     spanID,
            TraceFlags: trace.FlagsSampled,
        }),
    )

    // Create and start the root span with the custom TraceID and SpanID
    tracer := otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("my-tracer")
    _, rootSpan := tracer.Start(ctx, "root-span")
    defer rootSpan.End()

    // Your code here
    fmt.Println("Hello from root span!")
    createChildSpan(ctx)
    time.Sleep(10*time.Second)
}

// In another part of your code or a different process, you can create child spans
// referencing the custom root span created in step 1.

func createChildSpan(ctx context.Context) {
    tracer := otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("my-tracer")
    _, childSpan := tracer.Start(ctx, "child-span")
    defer childSpan.End()

    // Your code here
    fmt.Println("Hello from child span!")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).